# DLL plain text description

Tags: c++, dll

Dears, in side a DLL file, opened by Notepad++, I have the following function text:

```
cstaSetDisplay_CTI_3_0_0(%d,%d,%s,%02X,%d,%s)
```

can I know number of parameters from that text?

Comment: Are you asking how to count the number of percent sign characters in a string?

Comment: That text is probably from some debug `printf`, so it's possible that `cstaSetDisplay_CTI_3_0_0` takes `int, int, char*, unsigned, int, char*`. OTOH, this is not hard evidence - for example, those string parameters may just be something else that gets formatted to string beforehand for display. There's no easy way to know (unless the function itself is exported with C++ name mangling).

Comment: @MatteoItalia : One or more of those values being printed could easily be global (or member) variables

Comment: @MartinBonner: of course they could be anything, and the function could not even exist; the underlying assumption here is that when you write a debug print like that generally you replicate the number and order of parameters for ease of debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

That text is *text*. Anybody could write *any* text into a dll resources section. I could write "pink elephant" in my dll and there is no guarantee that that dll contains even traces of pink elephants.

Now you could make an educated guess and say if somebody used that as a format string to a printf-like function, chances are that he called it with 6 parameters. But again, that's a guess. There is no guarantee the function of that name is present or called *at all*.

Comment: But there is a function with that name in the DLL. but I dont know number of params

Comment: @ImadAbuHayyah So? Your best guess is 6. It's a **guess**. Either find a proper documentation or go with that guess.